# MS Access writes a decimal with the proper precision, but reads back a shorter precision

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a field on a subform (in MS Access, 2010) that is supposed to accept a decimal(6,5).  The *format* is set to "general number", and the *decimal places* are set to 5.

Any number I enter that has more than 2 decimal places saves correctly to the backend database, but after refreshing the form, it displays to the hundredths place.

For example, .5555 is rounded to .56

I have re-linked the table, confirmed that both the front-end and back-end are set to decimal(6,5), and tried several combinations of format and decimal places.  If it matters, the sub form is a continuous form.

Comment: You have tried those combinations where? What is textbox Format and DecimalPlaces properties set to?

Comment: try using format function like this: Format("563.6", "#0.0000000")